# How to loop getRange("B" + row + " :" + "J" + row) in google sheet editor script

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

```
function onEdit(evt) {

var range = evt.range;

showAutoValue(range);

}

function showAutoValue(range){

  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var activeSheet = spreadSheet.getActiveSheet();

  var row = range.getRow();

  var column = range.getColumn();

  if(column == 1 && row >= 1){

    var Avalue = activeSheet.getRange("A" + row).getValue();

    var B_Jrange = activeSheet.getRange("B" + row + ":" + "J" + row);

    if(String(Avalue).trim()){
      for(var i = 0; i < B_Jrange.length; i++){
        if(String(B_Jrange[i].getValue()).trim().toLowerCase() == "change moi"){
          B_Jrange[i].setBackground(Avalue);
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you please read [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you improve the level of detail in your question.

Comment: How about `var B_Jrange = activeSheet.getRange(row,2,1,9);` or `var Avalue = activeSheet.getRange(row,1).getValue();`

Answer (score 0):

**Selecting and Highlighting Ranges with onEdit()**

Okay I thought about this a bit more and I decided to make columnA a data validation list of white,yellow,lightgreen,lightblue because you must keep in mind that in order to generate the onEdit trigger you must actually change something. So in this case you're changing the background color of the range e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,2,1,8) to the value that's selected in column A of that row. So no loop is required to accomplish this.

```
function onEdit(e){
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(e.range.columnStart==1){
    if(String(sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1).getValue()).trim()){
      sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,2,1,8).setBackground(sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1).getValue()); 
    }else{
      sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,2,e.range.rowEnd,8).setBackground('white').getValue(); 
    }
  }
}
```

This version also clears the entire range if you select all of column A and hit return it sets column A to no selection and the second part of the if/else statement clears background of the entire range.

[image]

Comment: no, that's not what I want....I want to know how to browse the cells selected by the variable B_Jrange...
no browse values