# Google Script: onedit(e) e.value not registering delete key press as edit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Four months ago user Cooper was so kind to provide the below code to me.
Although it works great, I have two questions about it.

1.) in order for the onEdit function to trigger, I need to press delete on the keyboard twice. 
A single press only empties the cell value. Is there any workaround on this?

2.) Only the active cell is being edited, but not the range selection I draw. Is there a way to make onEdits edit full ranges?

Thank you very much for your assistance.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  //e.source.toast(' e.value: ' + e.value);
  if(sh.getName()!='Sheet4'){return;}
  if(e.range.rowStart<31 && e.range.columnStart<9 && !e.value) { //if in the range of A1:H30 and new value is blank
    var rg=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart); 
    rg.setFormula("=Sheet2!" + rg.getA1Notation());
    //e.source.toast('A1: ' + rg.getA1Notation() + ' e.value: ' + e.value);
  }  
}
```

Comment: "Is there a way to make onEdits edit full ranges?" You're using `rowStart` and `columnStart` There are two options: 1) just use e.range, OR 2) there's a `rowEnd` and `columnEnd` also; just add those to your "IF" statement. You can view the Event Objects by using `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))`.

Comment: " I need to press delete on the keyboard twice" That's not my experience. If I select a single cell; press the Delete Key; wait just a moment while Sheets registers that it is saving the sheet; then check the log, I find that the edit has been recorded.

Comment: It works for me too.

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58701648/7215091  It uses rowStart,rowEnd and columnStart to clear the entire range at one time.

Answer (score 0):

As [@Tedinoz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1330560/tedinoz) so kindly answered in the comments:

> "Is there a way to make onEdits edit full ranges?"

You're using rowStart and columnStart.

There are two options:
 1. Just use e.range
 2. There's a rowEnd and columnEnd also; just add those to your "IF" statement.

You can view the Event Objects by using Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))

> "I need to press delete on the keyboard twice"

That's not my experience. If I select a single cell; press the Delete Key; wait just a moment while Sheets registers that it is saving the sheet; then check the log, I find that the edit has been recorded.